# Highcharts columns data overlapped

Tags: highcharts

I would like to show a chart in column type but when a value is larger than others, values are not really shown (here 450 €): 
http://jsfiddle.net/gyeb3fg2/2/

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'percent',
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function () {
                  return this.y + ' €';
                },
                style: {
                  textShadow: '0 0 0 black'
                },
                crop: false,
                allowOverlap:true,
                verticalAlign:'middle'
            },
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{},
     {
        name: 'John',
        data:[8000,8000,8000,8000,8000] ,
         dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
          }
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [450,450,450,450,450],
         dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
          }
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [187500, 150000, 125000, 100000, 87500],
         dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
          }
    }]
```

i've tried to add a 'minPointLength' to PlotOptions#Column (to show label and value) , but with a 'large' value, column are overlapped like this : 
http://jsfiddle.net/gyeb3fg2/3/

```
column: {
            stacking: 'percent',
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function () {
                  return this.y + ' €';
                },
                style: {
                  textShadow: '0 0 0 black'
                },
                crop: false,
                allowOverlap:true,
                verticalAlign:'middle'
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            minPointLength:10
        }
```

with 'minPointLength' to 10, values are shown, but labels are overlapped. (allowOverlap:true because i would like to show labels but to false, all labels are not shown :/ )

with this series (this is an extreme case but a real case), i would like to show all values and labels with a minimal length), any ideas ?

thanks

sorry for my bad english

Comment: `minPointLength` for stacked series is under consideration/development, please take a part in [that discussion](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1776).

Comment: The question comes down to 'how do I fit more stuff than can actually fit in the space?'  There isn't really an answer to that. I would say the options are either moving the data labels outside the column, and making sure you space the columns far enough apart to handle the labels, or accept that the label for the tiny data points is not important in the context of the chart. If you need to show every data label, it becomes redundant, and I would opt to instead show the chart without labels, combined with a small table of the data values.